# Filtering Database Results to Top n Records for Each Value in a Lookup Column

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say I have two tables in my database.

```
TABLE:Categories
ID|CategoryName
01|CategoryA
02|CategoryB
03|CategoryC
```

and a table that references the Categories and also has a column storing some random number.

```
TABLE:CategoriesAndNumbers
CategoryType|Number
   CategoryA|24
   CategoryA|22
   CategoryC|105
   .....(20,000 records)
   CategoryB|3
```

Now, how do I filter out this data?  So, I want to know what the 3 smallest numbers are out of each category and delete the rest.  The end result would be like this:

```
TABLE:CategoriesAndNumbers
CategoryType|Number
   CategoryA|2
   CategoryA|5
   CategoryA|18
   CategoryB|3
   CategoryB|500
   CategoryB|1601
   CategoryC|1
   CategoryC|4
   CategoryC|62
```

Right now, I can get the smallest numbers between all the categories, but I would like each category to be compared individually.

EDIT: I'm using Access and here's my code so far

```
SELECT TOP 10 cdt1.sourceCounty, cdt1.destCounty, cdt1.distMiles
FROM countyDistanceTable as cdt1, countyTable
WHERE cdt1.sourceCounty = countyTable.countyID
ORDER BY cdt1.sourceCounty, cdt1.distMiles, cdt1.destCounty
```

**EDIT2: Thanks to Remou, here would be the working query that solved my problem.  Thank you!**

```
DELETE
FROM CategoriesAndNumbers a
WHERE a.Number NOT IN (
    SELECT Top 3 [Number] 
    FROM CategoriesAndNumbers b 
    WHERE b.CategoryType=a.CategoryType 
    ORDER BY [Number])
```

Comment: Looks like you need a "Top N per Group" query. [This KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296449) provides one solution and [another older one](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/153747)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
SELECT a.CategoryType, a.Number
FROM CategoriesAndNumbers a
WHERE a.Number IN (
    SELECT Top 3 [Number] 
    FROM CategoriesAndNumbers b 
    WHERE b.CategoryType=a.CategoryType 
    ORDER BY [Number])
ORDER BY a.CategoryType
```

The difficulty with this is that Jet/ACE Top selects duplicate values where they exist, so you will not necessarily get three values, but more, if there are ties. The problem can often be solved with a key field, if one exists :

```
WHERE a.Number IN (
    SELECT Top 3 [Number] 
    FROM CategoriesAndNumbers b 
    WHERE b.CategoryType=a.CategoryType 
    ORDER BY [Number], [KeyField])
```

However, I do not think it will help in this instance, because the outer table will include ties.

Comment: Well, the example I posted in my question contained dumb-down data; there is 99.9999% chance that there would be no duplicate values existing.  I modified your query so that instead of SELECT, I did DELETE and added NOT.  I'll add it to my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Order it by number and take 3, find out what the biggest number is and then remove rows where `Number` is greater than the `Number`.

I imagine it would need to be two seperate queries as your business tier would hold the value for the biggest number out of the 3 results and dynamically build the query to delete the rest.